# Need to send long string value to excel as expected

Tags: java, katalon-studio

I'am getting string value as (console view) [image: this]  my output is  (excel) [image: here] and I need to see the output as [image: this] in excel. any solution?

keyword

```
@Keyword
    public void demoKey(String name) throws IOException{

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\\\Decypha data files\\Demo1.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
        int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount+1);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(name);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\\\Decypha data files\\Demo1.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
```

test case

```
String str = arrlist.toString();
str = str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
System.out.println(str);
String listString = String.join(", ", str);
String[] arrOfStr = listString.split("\\|");
CustomKeywords.'WriteExcel.demoKey'(listString)
for (String a : arrOfStr)
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: You should put each of the values in a separate cell, not all of them in one cell.

Comment: yes . the output is one string(inside one cell). thinking about where should i change the code.

Comment: You are supposed to break the string into the pieces, and do appropriate `createRow()` for each line - not just one, and appropriate `createCell()` for each value.

Answer (score 1):

Call demoKey method inside for loop as given below.

```
for(String a:arrOfStr)
{
    System.out.println(a);
    CustomKeywords.`WriteExcel.demoKey'(a);
}
```

Comment: your method is correct , in excel how can i write one by one ? now its printing last string value in that excel .

Answer (score 0):

You are basically passing the entire string to a cell. Hence it's printing the entire string in a single cell. Spilt the string till for `,` and print first 8 values in cell and then increment the row count and print the next set of 8 string for next cell.